# C# Entity Framework LINQ to Entities adding parametric WHERE Expression underneath a SELECT Expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I am trying to select certain type of navigation property by passing an Id parameter to the WHERE Expression, but it fails with the following error;

"variable 'parkingLot' of type 'X.Models.ParkingLot' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined"

From searching S/O what I understand (if I am not mistaken) LINQ to Entities can not understand function bodied expressions. So what I would like to ask is, is there are way of achieving this functionality.

What I am trying to do is currently;

BaseService layer contains SelectAsync Function Expression> such that;

```
    public virtual async Task<List<TOut>> SelectAsync<TIn, TOut>(Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> selector) 
        where TIn : class, IBaseModel
    {
        List<TOut> retVal;
        using (var dc = new TContext() { Configuration = { ProxyCreationEnabled = false, AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false, LazyLoadingEnabled = false } })
        {
            retVal = await dc.Set<TIn>().AsNoTracking().Select(selector).ToListAsync();
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

From Service, I am calling related entites;

```
    var parkingLots = await SelectAsync(ParkingLotResponse.ResponseSelectExpr);
```

ParkingLotResponse.ResponseSelectExpr is follows;

```
    public class ParkingLotResponse
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        .
        .
        .

        public IEnumerable<ParkingLotServiceResponse> Services { get; set; }

        .
        .
        .

        public static Expression<Func<ParkingLot, ParkingLotResponse>> ResponseSelectExpr =
            parkingLot => new ParkingLotResponse()
            {
                Id = parkingLot.Id,
                .
                .
                .
                // If we use non-function bodied (which is right below this line), everything runs ok.
                // Services = parkingLot.Services.AsQueryable().Select(ParkingLotServiceResponse.ResponseSelectExpr),
                Services = parkingLot.Services.AsQueryable().Select(ParkingLotServiceResponse.ResponseSelectExprParkingLot(parkingLot.Id)), // This one is causing problem
                .
                .
                .
            };

    }
```

Where ParkingLotServiceResponse is;

```
public class ParkingLotServiceResponse
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ParkingLotServiceFareResponse> ServiceFares { get; set; }

        // This one is ok but can not select related subitems, thus returns all subitems
    public static Expression<Func<ParkingService, ParkingLotServiceResponse>> ResponseSelectExpr =>
        parkingLotService => new ParkingLotServiceResponse()
        {
            Id = parkingLotService.Id,
            ServiceFares = parkingLotService.ServiceFares.AsQueryable()
            .Select(ParkingLotServiceFareResponse.ResponseSelectExpr).AsEnumerable()
        };

        // This one is causing problem
    public static Expression<Func<ParkingService, ParkingLotServiceResponse>> ResponseSelectExprParkingLot(Guid parkingLotId) =>
        parkingLotService => new ParkingLotServiceResponse()
        {
            Id = parkingLotService.Id,
            ServiceFares = parkingLotService.ServiceFares.AsQueryable()
                .Where(ParkingLotServiceFareResponse.WhereBelongsToParkingLot(parkingLotId))
                //.Where(plsf => plsf.ParkingLotId == parkingLotId) // -> this is not working either
                .Select(ParkingLotServiceFareResponse.ResponseSelectExpr).AsEnumerable()
        };

}
```

Where ParkingLotServiceFareResponse is;

```
public class ParkingLotServiceFareResponse
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public static Expression<Func<ParkingLotServiceFare, ParkingLotServiceFareResponse>> ResponseSelectExpr =>
        parkingLotServiceFare => new ParkingLotServiceFareResponse()
        {
            Description = parkingLotServiceFare.Description,
            Price = parkingLotServiceFare.Price
        };

    public static Expression<Func<ParkingLotServiceFare, bool>> WhereBelongsToParkingLot(Guid parkingLotId) =>
        parkingLotServiceFare => parkingLotServiceFare.ParkingLotId.Equals(parkingLotId);

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: I think the problem is you are using static field inside Excpression,unlike you are outside the Experssion  eg:(`dc.Set<TIn>().Where( expression instance)`)  you can use a instance as long as it is a expression. And imagine what the expression will be when inside a expression .  it will be `Expression.Call(ParkingLotServiceFareResponse.ResponseSelectExpr)` instead a `Where Expression`

Comment: you should use `Expression.Call`/`Expression.Invoke`  to dynamicly create the expression

Comment: @John The thing is,

When I rewrite the following expression explicity;

  Services = parkingLot.Services.AsQueryable().Select(ParkingLotServiceResponse.ResponseSelectExprParkingLot(parkingLot.Id))

suc that;

  ServiceFares = parkingLotService.ServiceFares.Where(parkingLotServiceFare => parkingLotServiceFare.ParkingLotId == parkingLot.Id)
  .Select(parkingLotServiceFare => new ParkingLotServiceFareResponse()
      {
          Description = parkingLotServiceFare.Description,
          Price = parkingLotServiceFare.Price
  })

All is ok and able to Select only relevant items.

Comment: That's correct.  because u pass a intance of `Expression` , forexample :  `.Where(MyStaticFunction())`  is actrully `.Where(Expression)`, but if you call   `where` method insde `MyStaticFunction` then , it becase something like this:  `.Where(LambdaExpresion{ parameters:parameter1, body: call "MySecondStaticFunction" })`

Comment: There also another way ,that do not require dynamic build Expression,  you can use Method, to append `standand linq method` to the `IQueryable`,
`IQueryable<T>  DoMyWhere(IQueryable<T> query, string mycondition)
{  return query.Where(x=>x.filed == mycondition);  
}`
,  but it seems not fit for your case